# How to resolve gem install conflicts for fastlane v 2.162.0

Tags: rubygems, fastlane

I'm atttempting to update fastlane to the newest version running:

```
sudo gem install fastlane -v 2.162.0
```

And it's erroring out with

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyResolutionError)
    conflicting dependencies faraday (~> 0.12) and faraday (~> 1.0)
  Activated faraday-1.0.0
  which does not match conflicting dependency (~> 0.12)

  Conflicting dependency chains:
    fastlane (= 2.162.0), 2.162.0 activated, depends on
    faraday (~> 1.0), 1.0.0 activated

  versus:
    fastlane (= 2.162.0), 2.162.0 activated, depends on
    google-api-client (>= 0.37.0, < 0.39.0), 0.37.0 activated, depends on
    googleauth (~> 0.9), 0.9.0 activated, depends on
    faraday (~> 0.12)

  Gems matching faraday (~> 0.12):
    faraday-0.17.3
```

When I run

```
sudo gem list
```

It shows:

```
...
faraday (1.0.0, 0.17.3)
...
google-api-client (0.38.0)
...
googleauth (0.9.0)
...
```

Why is it saying google-api-client 0.37.0 activated if I uninstalled that version and only have 0.38.0 installed?

Answer (score 3):

I run into this issue too.

Based on [DanielRead's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64230448/419348), I execute following commands.

```
sudo gem cleanup
sudo gem update
sudo gem cleanup
sudo gem update
// ....
```

When `sudo gem update` upgrade fastlane to the latest version (2.163.0), I end up above command cycle.

1. `sudo gem cleanup` will remove redundant packages with old versions.
2. `sudo gem update` will update packages to latest version.

But, due to dependency conflicts, some package upgrading will fail. (ex: fastlane). So, continue above commands to resolve dependency conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why the problem happened, but I ended up fixing it by doing the following commands in order:

```
sudo gem uninstall faraday
sudo gem uninstall google-api-client
sudo gem uninstall googleauth
sudo gem update
sudo gem install fastlane -v 2.162.0
```